SSH works SSHFS doesn't and I don't know why
I'm trying to use SSHFS to mount some folders on my system. I'm basically just a "normal" user trying to access my media PC that way.
Things I have done so far:

I set up a SSH server on my media PC, with public key verification only.

The only thing I changed in the sshd_config are
PasswordAuthentication no  
AuthenticationMethods publickey

That worked fine for months now, I can run commands from my client PC and I'm able to access my files via SFTP. Now I wanted to also use SSHFS to mount some folders. I didn't think much and thought it would work right out of the box.
When trying to connect for the first time this message kinda confused me, since i already had connected with ssh before so i thought it should be known?
ED25519 key fingerprint is  SHA256:xxx.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no[fingerprint])
read: Connection reset by peer

Ever since i just keep getting:
Permission denied (publickey).
read: Connection reset by peer

I already checked the obvious things, e.g. if my public key is added to the authorized_keys file, if SSH is still working (which it does) and if the rights set up correctly for the .ssh folders. I also tried to specify my public key (although I use default settings) by:
sudo sshfs -o sshfs_debug,IdentityFile=/home/clientpc/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub mediapc@192.168.0.17:/home/mediapc/media /home/clientpc/mp3  

Which will then end up telling me:

executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-oIdentityFile=/home/clientpc/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub> <-2> <media@192.168.0.17> <-s> <sftp>
Load key "/home/clientpc/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub": error in libcrypto


Which I think might be the reason for this issue. When generating this keypair I didn't do anything fancy besides setting a passphrase for the file.
However I have no clue if this is what is causing me this problem.

It also says permission error make sure the only user who can access the file is the intended user of the key.

@KamilMaciorowski sadly i think that isn't the issue. I experimented now quite a bit with different strings. I also edited the post so it makes more sense what i actually entered. I don't use any fancy signs in folder or whatever so. I think it is related to the libcrypto error. Though i have no clue what to make of it.

I found the solution: I have no clue why this is the solution though the issue seemed to be using sudo. Without sudo it works. I feel stupid now.

Sudo causes the command to be elevated to another prompt session which likely was not properly configured to use the key. This is likely why the key fingerprint wasn't known and the reason the connection ultimately failed.

Ty. Should i "fix" this somehow so that it also works with sudo too or can that be ignored?
